# Mosfet array as FPGA power consumption model

Tags: power, mosfet

I would like to use an array of power mosfets as a model for an FPGA (i.e the mosfets will represent the FPGA as a model for the power dissipation).  For example if the total estimated power consumption of the FPGA is 150W and the max current 180A,  Would it be best to have a parallel or series array of mosfets for such a case?

Comment: Could you sketch a schematic for the "series array of mosfets" you are talking about? Also, using power MOSFETs to dissipate power (in linear mode presumably) is a bad idea, you'll get them in thermal runaway and burn them in no time.

Comment: Why not just use a bunch of parallel power resistors totalling about 5 milli ohm?

Comment: Just wondering: what are you going to use this for? Linear elements will be horrible representations for the filth that a running FPGA is going to insert onto your power lines.

Answer (score 2):

Using "power MOSFETS" to model FPGA power consumption is not a correct idea, they have no common features with mechanisms of power dissipation in digital logic.  The question about "parallel" or "in-series" doesn't seem to be well thought, FPGA use low-voltage power rails and "sereis" connecton of dissipation elements obviously has no place here.

Power dissipation of FPGAs depends on (a) static dissipation (via leakage), and (b) dynamic dissipation, which depends on how many gates are switching and at which frequency. Here is an [Altera/INTEL article](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/altera-www/global/en_US/pdfs/literature/wp/wp-01044.pdf) that provides overview of the models. The model obviously must rely on a particular logic design (because only then you can know the number of switching gates and their frequency), which can be determined only by VHDL compiler and associated power estimator tool.

But if you mean "thermal model" for some crazy 150W FPGA package with thermal spreader, then yes, any array of properly-distributed elements (resistors or power MOSFETS) will do the job, regardless of parallel or series connection.

Comment: Sorry that my initial question was so vague, yes I meant a thermal model so that cooling options could be considered and analyzed. From what I understand, the current will be split between the Mosfets when in parallel, what would the advantage of a series connection be?